# Swift: Accessing properties in a dictionary of structs

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct, properties

If I make an array of structs, everything works as expected, however if I make a dictionary of structs, their properties are no longer accessible, is there an added step to access them? See simple example below:

```
struct SceneStruct {
   var number: Int

   init(number: Int) {
       self.number = number
   }
}
let aStruct = SceneStruct(number: 0)  //shows in assistant editor as:  {number 0}
let bStruct = SceneStruct(number: 26) //shows in assistant editor as: {number 26}

//EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:
let arr = [aStruct,bStruct] //shows in assistant editor as: [{number 0}, {number 26}]
var i = arr[0] //shows in assistant editor as: {number 0}
var j = i.number //shows in assistant editor as: 0

//BROKEN BEHAVIOR:
let dict = ["one": aStruct, "two": bStruct] //shows in assistant editor as: ["one": {number 0}, "two": {number 26}]
var x = dict["one"] //shows in assistant editor as: {{number 0}}
var y = x.number // Fails: "error: 'SceneStruct?' does not have a member named 'number'"
```

It appears that objects are wrapped somehow in a dictionary, but for the life of me I can't find any information on this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For arrays, the subscript operator returns the value.

```
var i = arr[0] // <- i is of type SceneStruct
```

For dictionaries, the subscript operator returns an optional.

```
var x = dict["one"] // <- x is of type SceneStruct? (Optional< SceneStruct>)
```

The reason is `arr[100]` throws an exception because the array is out of bounds. Whereas `dict["invalid"]` returns `nil` the lookup failed.

You can workaround this difference in a few ways.

Evaluate with a default value

```
var defaultValue = SceneStruct(number: 0)
var x = dict["one"] ?? defaultValue // provide a default value if dict["one"] is nil.
var y = x.number
```

Conditional evaluation

```
if let x = dict["one"] { // conditionally set x
    var y = x.number
} else {
    // dict["one"] is nil
}
```

Forced unwrapped

```
var x = dict["one"]! // force unwrap dict["one"], this will throw an exception if dict["one"] is nil. 
var y = x.number
```

Comment: damn optionals ;) Thank you – that was, as I thought, a very simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

The result of subscripting a dictionary value by its key is an Optional value (a `SceneStruct?` in your case). You need to deal with that optional.

```
let dict = ["one": aStruct, "two": bStruct]
let x = dict["one"] // x is SceneStruct?
let y = x?.number // y is Int?
```